# jQuery animate() is running late

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that animated my image on the header. Is shrinks it when user scrolls down and enlarges it when user reaches the top. Here it is:

```
function headerScroll() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(document).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#headerContainer').addClass('smaller');
            $('#header img').animate({
                height: '170px',
                left: '414px',
                top: '10px'
            },200);
        } else if($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('#header img').animate({
                height: '307px',
                left: '361px',
                top: 0
            },200, function() {
                $('#headerContainer').removeClass('smaller');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is - sometimes (not always) secound animation doesn't run for a while. It sometimes wait a few secounds. How can I prevent it?

edit: when I added `alert('test')` either before or after `animate`, it ran well-timed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:  `$('#header img').animate().stop().animate(`....
Hope is work

Comment: I don't think you need two calls to animate, a simple call to stop before setting up the new animation should suffice, so is the issue resolved now @TomekBuszewski? if so then mark the answer as accepted